# Mini-Lags while debugging with Internet Explorer 11 and VS 2013 (IIS Express)

Tags: visual-studio, iis

I got my hands on Visual Studio 2013 and almost everything is working fine.
Only my ASP.NET Web Application (Target-Framework: .NET 4) seems to lag when I'm running it locally (Debug-Modus).

It seems like after every click, it loads the new site, then suddenly stop reacting for a few seconds (only the project; other applications as well as other sites opened in seperate windows are running fine), and then proceeds.

This problem only occurs with Internet Explorer (10 and 11), the project runs fine with Firefox/Chrome.
I don't have the problem when I'm running the same project with Visual Studio 2010.
Is there a setting/add-on or something that could be the cause for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After posting this over at the [ASP.NET forums](http://forums.asp.net) I got my [question](http://forums.asp.net/p/1966993/5625974.aspx?Re%20Mini%20Lags%20while%20debugging%20with%20Internet%20Explorer%2011%20and%20VS%202013%20IIS%20Express%20) answered.
The solution to my problem was to [disable the browser link](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link#disabling) in Visual Studio 2013.

[image]

(Thanks again PatriceSc for sorting this out)